# Can a app engine task get a count of the number of times it's been run?

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

I am running thousands of tasks per hour in Google App Engine and around .1% of them are failing even after multiple retries. Ideally, I want them to stop trying and exit. However, due to app engine's design they seem to be just trying again and again. I know there is a backoff time which increases with every unsuccessful execution, but I want them to exit after n retries altogether.

Can i accomplish this somehow? can a task get a count of the number of times it has unsuccessfully run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can get a count of the number of times your task has been retried by reading the [X-AppEngine-TaskRetryCount](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview.html#Task_Request_Headers) HTTP header.

Comment: For python it is: request.META.get('HTTP_X_APPENGINE_TASKRETRYCOUNT', '0')